# What function can I use for data of select range?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, mysql-workbench

I have a database of employees. There is a table named EMPS and in that table there is a column named Rate.

[image]

```
create table EMPS (empnum int, dept varhcar(20), surname varchar(50), phone varchar(50), rate float)
Insert into EMPS values(84,'L','HARVEY','445-8874',16);
Insert into EMPS values(85,'M','RUNGE','445-8876',16);
Insert into EMPS values(86,'Na','GIBTIN','432-1190',16);
Insert into EMPS values(87,'Op','JAMES','432-9943',14);
Insert into EMPS values(88,'P','SAND','456-8833',14);
Insert into EMPS values(89,'Q','OTIS','432-9951',16);
Insert into EMPS values(90,'R','BYRON','457-9355',16);
```

I want to select the average of rate values from EPMS where dept is between M and O. If there is more than one letter department like 'Ma' or 'Op' then those will be considered as M or O.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide sample data and desired result in text format (no nice screenshots)

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE emps; Do you want report of Average Rate from each unique department code between M and P?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 84 L HARVEY SALLY 55 HILL NEWTON AB T5N8U8 445-8874 16.00 3 45.00 85 M RUNGE DAN 430 SOUTH NEWTON AB T5R5G7 445-8876 16.00 0 100.00 86 N GIBTIN RITA 450 SOUTH NEWTON AB T6H9I0 432-1190 16.00 0 100.00 87 O JAMES NANCY 90 NORTH EDMONTON AB T6J9I9 432-9943 14.00 2 50.00 88 P SAND EMMA 67 NOBLE MORINVILLE AB T0K0K0 456-8833 14.00 0 100.00 89 Q OTIS ROB 333 NORTH NEWTON AB T5FY7H 432-9951 16.00 1 100.00 90 R BYRON LANCE 9U CENTRE NEWTON AB T0K3E3 457-9355 16.00 2 50.00 " here L,M,N,O,P are dept name and digits like 16.00, 45.00 are rate values. i have tried "between M and P" that didnt work

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *formatted* data. Placing in the comments makes it difficult to follow, and requires the reader to read both your question and all of the comments to assemble a complete picture of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate average rate for all the employees belong to department M, N, O or P.

```
select avg(rate) EMPRateCount from emps where left(dept,1)  in ('M','N','O','P');
```

And to calculate average rate for all the employees belong to department M, N, O or P but it will show the result department wise

```
     select avg(rate) EMPRateCount from emps where left(dept,1)  in ('M','N','O','P') 
group by department
```